# Calculate the determinant of a multilinear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, determinant, multilinear-algebra

How to calculate the determinant of a multilinear operator? Is it something different  from the determinant of the linear operator? Thanks.

Comment: The one and only case where one could arguably make sense of the determinant of a multilinear operator is that of a bilinear form $g : V \otimes V \to F$, for if we fix a non-degenerate bilinear form $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle$ on the finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $F$ (e.g., an inner product, if $F = \mathbb{R}$), then there exists a unique linear operator $G \in L(V,V)$ such that $g(v,w) = \left\langle Gv,w\right\rangle$ for all $v$, $w \in V$, in which case you could define $\det g := \det G$, if you absolutely wanted.

Comment: In more abstract terms, a choice of fixed non-degenerate bilinear form $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ canonically defines an isomorphism $V^\ast \cong V$, which yields, in turn, an isomorphism $$(V \otimes V)^\ast \cong V^\ast \otimes V^\ast \cong V \otimes V^\ast \cong L(V,V),$$ the operator $G$ is then the image in $L(V,V)$ of $g \in (V \otimes V)^\ast$ under this isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, it doesn't make sense to talk about the determinant of a multilinear operator. The usual determinant requires that the linear operator "start" and "end" at the same vector space: specifically, given a linear operator $T\colon V\to V$, where $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, applying [the $n$th exterior power functor $\Lambda^n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#The_exterior_power) produces a new linear operator $(\Lambda^nT)\colon \Lambda^n V\to\Lambda^nV$. Because $\Lambda^nV$ is a one-dimensional vector space, any linear operator from it to itself is necessarily given by multiplication by some scalar, and this scalar is the determinant of $T$. Observe that if we had started with a linear operator $T$ starting at a vector space $V$ and ending at a different vector space $W$, it would be impossible to identify this scalar; if $W$ is of a different dimension than $V$, there's no hope, because $\Lambda^n V$ and $\Lambda^n W$ will be of different dimensions, but even if $W$ is of the same dimension as $V$, it would be necessary to choose bases of $V$ and $W$ so that they (and hence also their exterior powers) could be identified in a consistent way.

In contrast, an $m$-linear operator (for $m>1$) looks like
$$V_1\times\cdots\times V_m\to W.$$
for some vector spaces $V_1,\ldots,V_m,W$, and the above process wouldn't be applicable.